# CSS positioning questions - do I use float, position, or display?

Tags: html, css, css-position

I wonder if anyone can help me understand a little more on positioning

I've read a lot of information regarding floats, position types and flex.
I understand the basics of it, but i´m having trouble with the simple things.

1. Which is the regular way professional front end developers use to positioning elements? Do they use `float`, `position: relative|absolute` or do they use flexbox or css grid? Or a combination of all?
2. Do professional developers use CSS reset everytime they make a new website?

I am making a header(it doesnt have a nav bar..just a logo and a title)
I want the logo to be on the left, and the title on the right.

So if i use inline-block i get this weird result where "World Guitars" is not aligned to the logo, but a little below.

```css
#logo {
  height: 60px;
  width: 50px;
  border: 2px solid #34495e;
  margin: 2px;
  align-self: center;
}

header p {
  font-family: Poppins;
  font-size: 2em;
  margin-left: 500px;
  align-self: center;
}

header p,
img {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <img src="images/logoGM.jpg" alt="logo" id="logo">
  <p>World Guitars</p>
</header>
```

If i do it with floats, it gets better, but its still so strange..

```css
header p {
  float: right;
  width: 900px;
}

header img {
  float: left;
}

section nav ul {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <img src="images/logoGM.jpg" alt="logo" id="logo">
  <p>World Guitars</p>
</header>
```

Finally in `position:relative`, and absolute I'm kind of lost.

Can i use position relative and assign values to my heart's content or is this not recommended?

How do i do it in this case?

Thank you!!

Comment: You can visualize what and why things are happening the way they are by using the developer console (press F12) and selecting the elements tab. Now you can hover over the elements and see exactly how the elements are being added to the DOM.  Playing around with these built in tools and reading a good blog on them will go a very long way to understanding the fundamentals.

Comment: Hi - pretty good question. 

You might want to splitting it into multiple questions. Also - note that you can embed runnable CSS and HTML into your question.

Comment: Also, keep in mind that "*the regular way professional front end developers use*" is really an open statement, you can approach positioning in a lot of ways, it really depends on what exactly you want to achieve and the benefits you expect as well as the compromises!

Comment: Hi - note that your images aren't going to work here - because they're referring to relative paths. Can you find some images on the internet and put the absolute paths in?

Comment: 1. They use the appropriate one for each circumstance. 2. No, but even if they did, that wouldn't automatically make it a good choice for beginners.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Display vs Position vs Float

In general I would say that the modern way to position elements is to use `display` properties - typically using `display:flex` or `display:grid` on parent elements to position their children, or using `display:block`, `display:inline` or `display:inline-block` on an element to position it self.

Where you would use `position:relative` and `position:absolute` is if you need to take an element out of flow. A typical case is if you need some elements to overlap. (ie. if you have three canvases that you are laying on top of each other).

Floats were a standard way of positioning elements (ie getting something to sit on the right of the page) in the old days. But now flex box has come along.

However - where you might want to use floats is if you want text to wrap around the element - like it might in a news paper. This is especially important as now HTML elements don't need to be rectangular. [See this example.](https://css-tricks.com/working-with-shapes-in-web-design/#shapes-shape-outside)

### CSS Resets

I use them. Why not.

These days, typically you might be using some kind of styling library like Material-UI or Bootstrap anyway, but yeah.

### In regards to what you're trying to do.

I would use flexbox here.

You have used 'align-self' here - but [align-self](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/align-self) only applies to a child of a flex parent.

```css
header {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  /*By default this is row wrap - I like to always be explicit with it*/
  align-items: center;
  /*center vertically, (because the flex flow is row*/
}

img {
  border: solid 2px black;
  max-height: 100px;
  /*size the image*/
  object-fit: scale-down;
  /*make the image keep it proportions*/
}

p {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 2em;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <img src="https://www.designevo.com/res/templates/thumb_small/black-wing-and-brown-guitar.png" alt="logo" id="logo">
  <p>World Guitars</p>
</header>
```

Comment: From your answer, I understand that 1. One should either use "display" or "position" property and not both. Is this correct ?

Comment: @vikramvi not at all . For example maybe you want to have an fixed container that sits in the corner of the screen, but you want its children to position themselves as flex children. in that case, the container would be `position:fixed; display: flex`.

Comment: I would caution against using the `position` property too much. Generally if you can you should be able to achieve what you need with display properties, especially display: flex and display: grid.

Comment: I'm learning web development and my understanding was position values `relative` & `absolute` are `must use` along with `display flex / Grid`. Can you please point me to good blogs, youtube which explains how to design web page fully with display property only ?

Comment: @vikramvi the resource I recommend is the MDN documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display also, Css tricks has a lot of good resources.

Answer (score 3):

I love answering questions like this! Feel free to add additional question comments. Source: I've been doing front-end web development for about 8 years.

Q1. Which is the regular way professional front end developers use to positioning elements?do they use float, position..relative,absolute..or do they use Flex?(or css grid?)Or a combination of all?

The short answer is a combination of all, but there is more to it than that. I would say most of the time developers will use a CSS framework like Bootstrap, Materialize, or Foundation. These frameworks provide a lot of abstraction over writing everything yourself, such as simply defining rows and columns using classes, and simple classes to define how those columns behave when resizing the screen. CSS Grid has a lot of the same concepts as these frameworks, but I would say it is less accessible if you are just starting out.

When it comes to writing custom CSS for things that are specific to your brand or project, I would say most of your larger scale positioning is done with relative positioning (such as padding, margin, width, etc) or flexbox. It is generally not a good idea to create your overall site structure out of absolute position elements or using floats for a few different reasons, which I can go into if you are interested, but positioning something on a small scale, using absolute positioning is common (For example a floating tooltip or a notification popup).

Q2. Do professional developers use CSS reset everytime they make a new website?

It depends. Many frameworks include CSS resets to ensure your website looks the same across browsers. I would generally say it saves time fixing things like odd button shadows in Firefox or extra input borders appearing in Safari.

In regards to your code question, I think this is a perfect application for flexbox! You said "title on the right" so I am unsure if this is exactly what you are looking for.

```css
header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.logo {
  height: 60px;
  width: 50px;
  border: 2px solid #34495e;
  margin: 2px;
}

.title {
  font-family: Poppins;
  font-size: 2em;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <img src="https://placeimg.com/50/60/any" alt="logo" class="logo">
  <p class="title">World Guitars</p>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

This depends on your needs and intent.  In terms of units, CSS has units that have an absolute size (think centimeters, etc.), and units that are scaled relative to the font size, or relative to the size of the viewport you're working inside.  There's no right or wrong unit to use, it depends on what you need.  Details on units are here: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp

In terms of whether to use flexbox or not, it can be a very useful tool if you want elements on the page to be able to scale dynamically, depending on the device or window size they're being displayed in.  You can also use it to create responsive pages without javascript, with a combination of flex-wrap and setting minimum widths for elements.  But not all designs benefit from flex, and sometimes you need elements that don't shrink or grow depending on the device they're being displayed on.  Grid is older than flex, but still useful.  It's very commonly used with bootstrap.

In terms of your specific example, I suspect the issue you're seeing is because your text is inside of a <p> block, which puts it on a new line.  Try putting it inside of a <span> block instead, and give that block an id so that you can set attributes for that ID in your css if you need to.

Comment: Careful with "*Grid is older than flex, but still useful*", just to clarify, **Grid** may refer to the layout system used by Bootstrap (also keep in mind Bootstrap 4 is all made on flexbox) and other column-based frameworks, but it may also refer (IMO it should refer to it) to **CSS Grid**, which is the latest layout system introduced after Flexbox for two-dimensional layouts: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/